# select rows based on exact time (hours, minutes and seconds)

Tags: plugin-development, sql

I want to update my wordpress posts based on exact time including hours, minutes and seconds, I tried the simple where clause, it seems ignoring the minutes and seconds, here is my simple query:

`$date = '2023-05-16 07:28:31'; $res = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID FROM wp_posts where post_date = '".$date."'");`
The result in this case return all the records with **2023-05-16**

but I want only the posts with the exact time.

Comment: is there a reason this is being done using raw SQL and not `WP_Query` and the date parameters? If you're going to do raw SQL you should use `$wpdb->prepare` to insert the variables rather than doing it directly so that it's safer

Answer (score 0):

Try $date = '2023-05-16T07:28:31';